# Developing a linear time algorithm to traverse a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, maps, analysis

I'm going through an algorithms textbook to improve my algorithm skills but I'm completely stuck on this question and it's bugging me. I think the underlying data structure is a graph but I don't even know where to begin with this problem. Can anyone give some insight? Thanks

> You are given a topographical map that provides the maximum altitude
>   along the direct road between any two neighboring cities, and two
>   cities a and b. Come up with an a linear time algorithm that finds a
>   route from s to t that minimizes the maximum altitude. Roads can be
>   traversed in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky question.  I would assume that there are some hints in the chapter that are supposed to guide you towards the solution.

The problem you are describing is an instance of the minimax path problem, or widest path problem.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem

According to wikipedia, there is a linear time algorithm, but it is pretty complicated, so I doubt the book expects you to figure that out.  The simpler way to solve this problem is to find a minimum spanning tree.  Due to the "min cut" property of a minimum spanning tree, the path connecting a and b along a minimum spanning tree will have the minimax property, meaning that the maximum altitude along this path will be the minimum of any path connecting a to b.

However, there is no linear time minimum spanning tree algorithm.  On the other hand, if we can assume that the graph is planar -- which we probably can since it is a road map -- then it is possible to find a minimum spanning tree in linear time.  So I think this is what they might be after.  Does the chapter containing this problem talk about minimum spanning trees and/or planar graphs?

Comment: Why do you think you can assume that none of these roads includes a bridge over another road?